# In R how to turn "NA" to " " on an imported file?

Tags: r, na

I have the following script:

```
datafilename <- "file.txt"
person.data  <- read.table(datafilename, header=TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", " "))
print(person.data)
```

What I want is for every "NA" that is in the file to be replaced with nothing and for R to assume in future calculations/plots that that value simply does not exist. How would I go about this?

PS: Sorry new in R, if you need more information please leave a comment.

**UPDATE - Plotting code**

```
datafilename <- "file.txt"
person.data  <- read.table(datafilename, header=TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", " "))

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- abs(cor(x, y))
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
  txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}

panel.regression <- function (x, y, col = par("col"), bg = NA, pch = par("pch"), 
                              cex = 1, col.regres = "red", ...) 
{ 
  points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex) 
  ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y) 
  if (any(ok)) 
    abline(stats::lm(y[ok] ~ x[ok]), col = col.regres, ...) 
} 

pairs(~O3_s+NO2_s+CO_s+O3_ref+NO2_ref+CO_ref, data=person.data,
      upper.panel=panel.regression, lower.panel=panel.cor, 
      pch=20, main="Plot")
```

Comment: If your `person.data` reads fine using your `read.table` then the the `NA` cells behave exactly the way you want them to.

Comment: How is turning it to "nothing" (really a string with one blank character) any different for the purposes of future calculations than using NA? I mean it's easy enough to do, but I don't thin it will achieve what you want.

Comment: What I'm trying there isn't working like I wanted it to... when printing person.data it should print an empty space instead of NA. Because when I leave the file with NA and then do some plots the NA actually shows up in them

Comment: Please add the plotting code. As @Elin said, whether they are represented in the output as NA or blanks is irrelevant -- they will not be used for computation in the first case.

Comment: Is it the printing of the correlations in the lower panel that is causing 
the problem? If so, you can change the `panel.cor` function to 
`txt <- ifelse(is.na(r), "", format(r, digits=digits))`, so the `NA`'s are 
printed as empty strings. (although perhaps you want to look at the `use="pairwise"` 
argument of `cor` instead)

Comment: I tried the ifelse and on the plot instead of NA it was an empty string but what I want is for it to return a value taking into consideration NA exists but isn't supposed to be taken into account. I'll take a look at the pairwise.

Comment: oh, i thought you wanted `NA` to be `""`.  But yep, as you are using `lm` which uses pairwise non-missing data, it seems sensible to use `cor(x, y, use="pairwise")`

Comment: Yup pairwise worked! Thanks a lot mate! put it as an answer and I'll upvote it and accept it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function that is causing the problem in this case is `panel.cor`.

By turning the `r <- abs(cor(x, y))` inside the `panel.cor` into `r <- abs(cor(x, y,use="pairwise"))` the plots will turn out the way you want them to.

[More information on `cor()` function and its arguments.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html)